# TFS Post Build Script

Tags: post, tfs, build

We have a TFS project and with a Visual Studion solution and with a MVC and a WCF projects in the solution. For the web project, I want to be able to change the TFS automated build to be able to delete and rename a java script file from within a folder (~/Web.UI/Scripts/Custom is the folder where the file needs to be renamed)in the Web project every time a deploy to a IIS site is done using the TFS automated build and deploy.

Can someone point me as to how this can be achieved using a TFS post build script?

Comment: You are using TFS 2013? If so, the new build template allows you to add a PowerShell script. Or is your problem in writing the PowerShell script itself?

Comment: Thanks for your response. We use TFS 2012. I have two problems. I have never modified a Build Template so I would like to see an example as to how to do it and also if possible an example of a Powershell script for the rename / delete of the file that I am intending to do.

Comment: Have a look at the TFS Build Extensions: https://github.com/tfsbuildextensions/CustomActivities/wiki/Getting%20started%20with%20the%20InvokePowerShellCommand%20activity